# Configure port forwarding in virtual machine or router

Tags: virtualbox, port-forwarding

I just installed ubuntu server in my virtual machine. I want to ask regarding port forwarding.

1. Do i need to port forward in router and virtual machine or either one?
2. Why virtual machine have their own port forward settings and from my understanding, port forward is important to be done in router?

Comment: Running a VM solution you create an independent network within your own computer. As such you might need further port forwarding depending on your network setup. So you might need it in both places or just one. It depends on what you configured and what you want to do.

Comment: What is your goal with this setup?

Comment: i am creating my own web server at home

Answer (score 0):

1. probably both, if an external party needs to contact your Ubuntu system.
2. Port forwarding on a given system means that when a connection is made to that system on a given port, the system will not handle that connection itself, but forward all trafic to another system that should handle it.  Your VM and the Ubuntu client are two separate systems.